# How to evaluate variable within `sed` command?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, gawk

I have a variable called "num", that holds a number.  I want to use it in "sed" like so:

```
sed '1,$(num)d' file.txt
```

also tried:

```
sed '1,($num)d' file.txt
```

...so that I can delete lines from 1 until the line `num`.

It gives me an error like this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `('
```

What is the correct way to do this?  thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell variable usage was incorrect. First, using the double quote ensures that the shell will expand the variable. Second, surrounding the variable in question (`num`) with the braces ensures that the variable will be seen by the shell as `$num`, instead of the subsequent `d` getting glommed on.

Here is how you should specify what you want to do:

`sed "1,${num}d" file.txt`

Comment: I thought of that, but I thought that the double quotes `""` don't expand the `{}`, because they only expand slashes, backticks, and dollar signs. I guess they also expand `{}`?

Comment: Surrounding a variable name with braces is how the shell disambiguates the characters making up a variable from any trailing characters that should not be a part of the variable name

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes but need to concatenate the script

```
num=42; seq 1 45 | sed '1,'$num'd'
```

will print

```
43
44
45
```

as expected.